# C# WPF Dual DropsShadowEffects for Neumorphism

Tags: c#, wpf, dropshadow

I am trying to accomplice Neumorphism effect on listview.

```
<ListView.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Border Background="#FFFFFF" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="0">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="6" Opacity="0.35" ShadowDepth="2" />
            </Border.Effect>
            <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ListView.Template>
```

It is only possible to add **ONE** DropShadowEffect for each listview. Anyone have a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can just continue [nesting via containment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/greg_schechter/using-effects-in-wpf-part-2#multi-input-effects).

Here I've added another `Border` inside the first and applied a second `DropShadowEffect`.

```xml
<ListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="32" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.Items>
        <TextBlock Text="Item 1" />
        <TextBlock Text="Item 2" />
        <TextBlock Text="Item 3" />
        <TextBlock Text="Item 4" />
    </ListView.Items>
    <ListView.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Border>
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="4" ShadowDepth="5" Color="Orange" />
                </Border.Effect>
                <Border>
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="8" ShadowDepth="10" Color="Green" />
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </Border>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListView.Template>
</ListView>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. Unfortunately that does not work. It gives the item inside the Listview a shadow. I am looking for two shadows on the Listview

Comment: To be clear, the `ListView` itself, or each `ListViewItem`?

Comment: Ahh sorry for being unclear... Each ListViewItem got the shadow effect when doing the above (nesting). My goal is to have two shadow effect on the ListView. Thanks!